# use arial embbed font in latex

Tags: pdftex

I would like to use font the same as a sample pdf file. from the sample pdf file properties dialog, I found the font name is "Arial (embedded)":
[image]

How should I use "Arial (embedded)" font in latex document?

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[] at (0,0) {hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[] at (0,0) {hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You should build with `xelatex`.

Comment: Any command to install the package? I saw below error: ! Package fontspec Error: The font "Arial" cannot be found.

Comment: Arial has installed in Windows. If you don't have Arial, you can copy them from Windows.

Comment: Oh, I am using ubuntu, where is the font file in windows? May I just copy it to linux?

Comment: In `C:\Windows\Fonts`, there are `ariali.ttf`, `arialbi.ttf`, `arialbd.ttf` and `arial.ttf`. You can read the doc of `fontspec` for how to make `fontspec` to find your font on Linux. Or you can set font by font filename, such as `\setmainfont[BoldFont=arialbd.ttf,ItalicFont=ariali.ttf,BoldItalicFont=arialbi.ttf]{arial.ttf}`. In this time, you can just put these font files in the same folder of `.tex`. You can also use font in TeX Live, such as `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}`.

Comment: In general, you do not not need to build with xelatex. You can build with lualatex, if the only issue is using a font such as Arial. But this specific user may be using other packages that require xelatex? In all cases: Arial does not have an entirely free license. That is outside the scope of TeX.